# Handling the google interactive post onclick via javascript

Tags: google-plus

My scenario is as follows:

Our application is building on top of google-plus and takes advantage of the google-plus connections.

Is this supported with Interactive posts? I want to:

1. Block showing the interactive post dialog on the button click if a certain condition is not met
2. Perform a certain action once the button to show the dialog is clicked - onClick works for this but I could not find documentation on it.

   ```
   var options = {
           contenturl: url,
           clientid: googleappid,
           cookiepolicy: "single_host_origin",
           prefilltext: text,
           calltoactionlabel: "START",
           calltoactionurl: ctaurl,
           recipients: connectionid,
           onClick: specialFunctionToRunOnClick(params)
    };             
    gapi.interactivepost.render('submitInvitationongoogle', options);
   ```

Is there something like beforeSend that can prevent the click from firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is not an API for testing whether the user has created an interactive post on their stream. You can know when the interactive post was rendered to the user by logging the API calls for [gapi.interactivepost.render](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#gapi.interactivepost.render) and can use the call-to-action url for testing when the recipient clicked the button. You can also look at their public stream activity to test whether the post was shared publicly but this is probably not what you want.

Comment: I am not looking to just setup the button programmatically. I want to invoke an ajax call on our server to track the action when this share post button is invoked. I am not sure how to hook into the click event that is wired for the button with the g-interactivepost class.

Comment: The onClick works for doing operations once the user has clicked. Is there a way to block showing an interactive post in javascript if a certain condition has not been met? For example - it is a requirement in our app to fill out certain fields required before the onClick function is called. However, I am not able to block showing the interactive post or calling the onClick function if that is not fulfilled.

Comment: It's totally possible to trigger or render the interactive post programatically. For example, here is an article on selectively rendering either the interactive post button or the share button : http://gusclass.com/blog/2013/03/11/selectively-rendering-interactive-posts/